# Cannot boot into Ubuntu after trying to install Wine32

Tags: boot, wine

I tried to install wine32 using "sudo apt install wine32". The installer made me reboot my PC and ever since I have just been returned to a black screen. I have some files there I need access to. What can I do to restore it? I have a backup, but with an older version of ubuntu so I want to avoid it. I cant remember what i did, but I managed to boot into the terminal version of ubuntu if thats relevant. I am quite new and still learning. Thanks :)

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Hi! I am using the latest release 21.10 i believe. I have a backup from some time ago using the LTS 20.04 version. Thanks